# Изменение значения aria-label при нажатии на кнопку на JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть кнопка, которая сворачивает и разворачивает блок, изначально в aria-label установлено значение "Скрыть заметку". Нужно при нажатии на кнопку(сворачивании блока) менять значение aria-label на "Открыть заметку"

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#qwerty');
        btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.target.textContent == 'Скрыть заметку' ? e.target.textContent = 'Открыть заметку' : e.target
                .textContent = 'Скрыть заметку';
        });
```

```html
  <button id="qwerty">Скрыть заметку</button>
```